# Array of Object of Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object

Basically I'm trying to create an array of objects, that has two arrays inside of it, however when I try and populate these I keep getting a null pointer, but when I populate the object without making an array of objects it seems to work.

And I keep getting -->
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CardTrick{
    int[] combo;
    int[] cardTeller;

    public CardTrick() 
    {
        combo = new int[3];
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            combo[j] = 0;
        }
        cardTeller = new int[2];  
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cardTeller[j] = 0;
        }   
    }

    public CardTrick(CardTrick c) { // notice the parameter is an object

        combo = new int[3];
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            combo[j] = 0;
        }
        cardTeller = new int[2];  
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cardTeller[j] = 0;
        }   

    }
    public void whatCards(){
        int num = 0;
        CardTrick[] list = new CardTrick[56];

        list[0].combo[1] = 1;
        list[0].combo[2] = 1;
        list[0].cardTeller[0] = 1;
        list[0].cardTeller[1] = 1;

        System.out.println(list[0].combo[1]);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        CardTrick ct = new CardTrick();
        ct.whatCards();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you share the stack trace as well?

Comment: @flakes I'll try to edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in these lines of code

```
CardTrick[] list = new CardTrick[56];

list[0].combo[1] = 1;
```

You created an array of objects, but your objects themselves aren't instantiated thus the `NullPointerException` is thrown.

You have to instantiate each cell of the array before accessing it

```
CardTrick[] list = new CardTrick[56];
list[0] = new CardTrick();

list[0].combo[1] = 1;
```

Comment: Perfect explanation. Don't forget you can also use `Arrays.fill(list, new CardTrick())`

Comment: @KnowNoTrend Won't that just fill the entire array with exactly the same object (which is most probably not what you want in that case)?

Comment: @brimborium they don't randomize the cards. they'll be the same anyway.